# (AWK) Csv separating same variables in columns into different files

Tags: awk, sed, grep, csv

I have a test1.csv file with two columns

```
group,email
group1@email.com,user1@email.com
group1@email.com,user2@email.com
group1@email.com,user3@email.com
group1@email.com,user4@email.com
group2@email.com,user5@email.com
group2@email.com,user6@email.com
group3@email.com,user7@email.com
group3@email.com,user8@email.com
group3@email.com,user9@email.com
```

My goal is to create separate text files depending on the value of the first column.

For example:

the first file named **group1@email.com** and containing

```
user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user3@email.com
user4@email.com
```

the first file named **group2@email.com** and containing

```
user5@email.como
user6@email.com
```

and so on.

I have this awk command

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1{header=$0}NR>2&&!a[$1]++{print header > (""$1"")}NR>2{print > (""$1"")}' test1.csv
```

but the result is not really what I'm looking for, although the naming of the files is correct:

```
group,email
group1@email.com,user2@email.com
group1@email.com,user3@email.com
group1@email.com,user4@email.com
```

I'm also getting an 'Awk: too many open files' whenever the .csv file is too big

Any help is appreciated. Also looking into different languages such as sed or grep

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information: Is the input file sorted, as is the example you provide? Do you want the headers in the output files too? If yes, add them to the expected output. (I suspect yes because in your attempt you really seem to be trying to include the header, but I missed it in my first parse of the question.)

Comment: Ciao Giuseppe, I have added a mlr based solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591041/195582

Comment: Should all output files start with the header line or none of them or what?

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR<2{next} p1!=$1&&p1{close(p1)} {p1=$1;print $2>p1}' file
```

- `NR<2{next}`: Skip header.
- `p1!=$1&&p1{close(p1)}`: When the 1st field of previous line (`p1`) is different from the 1st field of the current line, the previous output file is closed, so that you don't get "too many open files" (unless no file was opened yet and `p1` is unset).
- `{p1=$1;print $2>p1}`: Put 1st field in `p1` variable and print 2nd field to a file with the name of the 1st field.

Notice that the above awk assumes that lines with same first fields are grouped together in `file`, as the provided sample indicates. If this is not the case, a straightforward solution is to provide a sorted input to awk, explicitly skipping the header (since the header would not be in the first line anymore):

```
sort file | awk -F ',' '/^group,email$/{next} p1!=$1&&p1{close(p1)} {p1=$1;print $2>p1}'
```

Comment: You need to sort first if you `close`. If the group appears again then opening to write again will erase any previous content.

Comment: @bu5hman In my answer I considered that OP's file sample being sorted as not accidental. But, yes, we know that sometimes new users miss those important details when providing a minimal, reproducible example. Thank you for your remark, I'm adding that assumption in the answer itself.

Comment: You could `tail -n +2 file | sort | ` to lose the header and avoid the need to test every line.

Answer (score 1):

You can `awk` to redirect `$2` straight to the filename given in `$1` (domain names should be whitespace safe)

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{print $2 > $1}' file
```

Though this skips the header and leaves files open. You can fix this by testing if this is a new file `++h[$1]==1` to write `>` a header, use append `>>` for `$2` and then `close($1)`

```
awk -F, '
  NR==1{header=$0}
  NR>1{
    if(++h[$1]==1)print header > $1; 
    print $2 >> $1; close ($1)
}' file
```

And to avoid duplicates just test on `++f[$0]==1`before appending..

```
awk -F, '
  NR==1{header=$0}
  NR>1&&++f[$0]==1{
    if(++h[$1]==1)print header > $1; 
    print $2 >> $1; close ($1)
}' file
head *.com

==> group1@email.com <==
group,email
user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user3@email.com
user4@email.com

==> group2@email.com <==
group,email
user5@email.com
user6@email.com

==> group3@email.com <==
group,email
user7@email.com
user8@email.com
user9@email.com
```

If your file is wholly or partially sorted then you can avoid blindly opening and closing at every line by

```
awk -F, '
  NR==1{header=$0}
  NR>1&&++f[$0]==1{
    if ($1 != old) close(old);
    if(++h[$1]==1)print header > $1; 
    print $2 >> $1; old=$1
}' file
```

Because this uses `$2 >>`  it doesn't matter if there is a second chunk of `$1`  in your data file, it won't be erased by a fresh `>`

Comment: the OP's sample output files do not contain a header, so your solution shouldn't be needing one.  For closing files on exit, this may be simpler `awk -F, 'NR>1{a[$1];print $2 > $1};END{for (k in a) close(k)}' file`

Comment: OP code shows that they want a header. As far as your one liner goes it still keeps all the file handles open until the end. Anyway, am sure OP can make up their own mind as to what suits.

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is simply

```
mlr --csv put -q 'tee > $group, $*' ./input.csv
mlr -I --c2n cut -f email ./group*@*
```

It's not awk, but I think it could be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

you can make a unique list of first field and store in a variable for example `mygroups`

```
mygroups=$(awk -F ',' '{print $1}' test.csv | sort | uniq)
```

Then you can match column 1 with variable in each line

```
for i in $(echo $mygroups); do awk -F ',' -v val="$i" '$1==val {print $2}' test.csv >> "$i" ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print (NR>1),$0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -d' ' -f2- |
    awk -F, '
        NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
        $1 != out { close(out); out=$1; print hdr > out }
        { print $2 " > " out }
    '
```

The above will work using any awk for practically any size input file with the input lines in any order and it will be fast.

Change `print $2 " > " out` to `print $2 > out` once done testing to actually generate the output files.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU version of sed and writing in its extended mode we run the first pass over the csv input and from it generate the necessary series of sed code. In the second pass we apply this code on the csv and get our required .com filest
The deduplication is handled within the sed first pass itself.

```
sed -Ee '
  1s|.*|1b|
  1! s|(.*),.*|/^\1,/ s///w \1|
  G
  /^([^\n]*)\n(.*\n)?\1(\n|$)/d
  P;h;d
' test1.csv | sed -nf - test1.csv
head *.com
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
for i in `awk -F "," '{print $1}' p.txt| awk '{if(!seen[$1]++){print $1}}'`; do awk -v i="$i" -F "," '$1==i {print $2}' p.txt > $i.txt; done



output

$ cat group1@email.com.txt 
user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user3@email.com
user4@email.com

cat group2@email.com.txt 
user5@email.com
user6@email.com

$ cat group3@email.com.txt 
user7@email.com
user8@email.com
user9@email.com
```